# React app crashed when trying to submit with empty input field

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, schema, nodemon

please help me with this problem as I searched all the Internet but couldn't find the answer :(

I'm making a website using MERN Stack and I'm encounting a problem which is:

> Whenever I click **Update** on the **empty input field**, my app would crash.
>
> When I catch the error in the Axios update request, it just says **Network Error**.

I want to ask if there's anyway to fix this error?
Maybe if the input field is empty, the Update button won't fire?

**Here's my code:**

```
// DinnerIdeas.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import './DinnerIdeas.css'
import Axios from "axios"

import FoodListComponent from "../FoodListComponent";
import FormComponent from "../FormComponent";

function DinnerIdeas() {

    const [foodName, setFoodName] = useState('')
    const [isVegetarian, setVegetarian] = useState(false)
    const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('$')
    const [newFoodName, setNewFoodName] = useState(null)
    const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])
  
    // Read:
    useEffect(() => {
      let unmounted = false
      Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/read")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setFoodList(response.data)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`)
        return
      })
      return () => {
        unmounted = true
      }
    }, [foodList])
  
    // Create:
    const addToList = () => {
      Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/insert", 
        {
          foodName: foodName,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
          priceRange: priceRange,
        }
      )
    }
  
    // Update:
    const updateFood = (id) => {
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
        id: id,
        newFoodName: newFoodName,
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`))
    }
  
    // Delete:
    const deleteFood = (id) => {
      Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete/${id}`)
    }
    
    return (
      <section className="dinner-ideas">
        <FormComponent
          setFoodName={setFoodName}
          setVegetarian={setVegetarian}
          setPriceRange={setPriceRange}
          addToList={addToList}
        />
        <FoodListComponent 
          foodList={foodList} 
          setNewFoodName={setNewFoodName}
          updateFood={updateFood} 
          deleteFood={deleteFood}
        />
      </section>
    );
  }
  
  export default DinnerIdeas;
```

**FormComponent:**

```
export default function FormComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div className="dinner container">
            <h1 className="dinner--title">Dinner Ideas</h1>
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Food name:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="Ex: Pesto Pasta"
                        maxLength="50"
                        onChange={(event) => {props.setFoodName(event.target.value)}}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="vegetarian"> Is this dish Vegetarian?</label>
                    <select
                        name="vegetarian"
                        onChange={(event) => {props.setVegetarian(event.target.value)}}
                    >
                        <option value="false">No</option>
                        <option value="true">Yes</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="price">Price range:</label>
                    <select
                        name="price"
                        onChange={(event) => {props.setPriceRange(event.target.value)}}
                    >
                        <option value="$">$</option>
                        <option value="$$">$$</option>
                        <option value="$$$">$$$</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br />
            </form>
                <button 
                    type="submit"
                    className="dinner--btn" 
                    onClick={props.addToList}
                >
                    Add to list
                </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Server side: index.js**

```
const express = require("express") // Set up an express server
const mongoose = require("mongoose") // Import Mongoose library
const cors = require('cors') // Import CORS to communicate with frontend
const app = express() // Initializing our express server

const DinnerModel = require('./models/Dinner')

app.use(express.json()) // Setting up Middleware
app.use(cors())

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://higherstates:<password>@crud.cvewg.mongodb.net/dinner_ideas?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    }
)

// Create:
app.post("/insert", async (req, res) => {
    const foodName = req.body.foodName
    const isVegetarian = req.body.isVegetarian
    const priceRange = req.body.priceRange

    const dinner = new DinnerModel(
        { 
            foodName: foodName, 
            isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
            priceRange: priceRange,
        }
    )

    try {
        await dinner.save()
        res.send("data inserted")
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

// Read:
app.get("/read", async (req, res) => {
    DinnerModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        res.send(result)
    })
})

// Update:
app.put("/update", async (req, res) => {
    const newFoodName = req.body.newFoodName
    const id = req.body.id

    try {
        await DinnerModel.findById(id, (err, updatedFood) => {
            updatedFood.foodName = newFoodName
            updatedFood.save()
            res.send("update")
        }).clone()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("The error is: " + err)
    }
})


app.delete("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id

    await DinnerModel.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec()
    res.send("deleted")
})

// Creating a port:
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server is up on: http://localhost:3001")
})
```

**FoodListComponent:**

```
export default function FoodListComponent(props) {
return (
    <div className="food-list container">
        <h1 className="food-list--title">Food List</h1>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th className="th--name">Name</th>
                <th className="th--vegetarian">Vegetarian</th>
                <th className="th--price">Price</th>
                <th className="th--edit">Edit</th>
                <th className="th--actions">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.foodList.length > 0 && props.foodList.map((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={key}>
                        <td>{val.foodName}</td>
                        <td>
                            {val.isVegetarian ? <input type="checkbox" checked readOnly /> : <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" readOnly  />}
                        </td>
                        <td>{val.priceRange}</td>
                        <td>
                        <input
                            name="edit"
                            placeholder="New food name.."
                            size="15"
                            maxLength="50"
                            onChange={(event) => {props.setNewFoodName(event.target.value)}}
                        >
                        </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                className="table--btn"
                                onClick={() => props.updateFood(val._id)}
                            >
                                Update
                            </button>
                            <button 
                                className="table--btn"
                                onClick={() => props.deleteFood(val._id)}
                            >
                                ❌
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Mongoose Schema:**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    const DinnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        foodName: {
            type: String,
            default: true,
        },
        isVegetarian: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
        },
        priceRange: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    })

const Dinner = mongoose.model("Dinner", DinnerSchema)
module.exports = Dinner
```

**Here's the demonstration:**

1. If I click on the **Update button** without filling in the **Edit field**, it won't do anything but the data disappears when I refresh the page.
Error message in the console:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyAtQ.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72k3x.gif)
[Demonstrating gif]

2. The app crashed and here's the error message in the server's terminal

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgayZ.jpg
[nodemon app crashed error]

Thanks everyone!

Comment: did you try to fix the CORS error because probably you send request to another domain than your react app ?

Comment: I think the error is clearly visible. in the mongo schema, name is `required` and you're sending an empty value. If you intend to allow empty values then modify the schema to allow it. or prevent the API call to happen when the value is empty using client side validation

Comment: It seems foodName is required and you don't have any null checks for foorName

Comment: @programoholic I changed my Schema from `required: true` to `default: undefined`. Now the Update button won't submit empty value anymore but the FormComponent above, when I click "Add to list", it takes in empty value to the database.
Is there any way we can fix this?

Comment: @RamRana Hi, where should we put the null check? Can you tell me more about this? Thanks :)

Comment: @HDM91 I tried to search for the error but it doesn't have a status code. Can you tell me at which line do you think it's another domain? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to stop saving undefined value, I mean to not do put operation ?

Comment: @RamRana I want to do axios.put operation on the `FoodListComponent.js`'s input field because I want to make an Update operation for my CRUD app so users can edit the `foodName` (`newFoodName` state) after submitting the form (`FormComponent.js`). Can we **not** save empty input field but still received required input field (`foodName` in `FormComponent.js`) ?

Comment: // Update:
    const updateFood = (id) => {
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
        id: id,
        newFoodName: newFoodName,
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`))
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Update:
    const updateFood = (id) => {
if(newFoodName){
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
        id: id,
        newFoodName: newFoodName,
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`))
    }
}
```